# How to make matrix multiplication function in C? (static variables & arbitrary matrix size)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mat_mul(double** A, double** B,double **C, int M, int N, int K)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}

int main() {
    double A[3][3];
    double C[3][3] = { 0 };
    double B[3][3];


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) B[i][i] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            A[i][j] = 3 * i + j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf(" %lf", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    mat_mul(A, B, C, 3, 3, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make matrix multiplication function in C with static variables & arbitrary matrix size.
Above code has error.
How can I fix that error?

And I want to make function for any size matrix multiplication not only 3 by 3 matrix.

Comment: You should show us the errors you get. This could prove useful. Then you should take a look at dynamic memory allocation. If you want dynamic matrix size this is the way to go and clearly you are missing this.

Comment: @coincoin No need for that in this case. `double**` isn't compatible with `double (*)[3]` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to pointer is not an array, nor a 2D array, nor can it be used to point at an array. A conforming compiler will not let this code through since it isn't valid C.

Fix this by forgetting that you ever heard of pointer to pointer in relation with 2D arrays. Instead change the function to something like this:

```
void mat_mul(size_t x, size_t y, double a[x][y], double b[x][y], double c[x][y]);
```

This works as long as you pass a correct 2D array, no matter how it was allocated. You can allocate one dynamically like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// get x and y from user input etc:
int x = something;
int y = something;

double (*array)[y] = malloc( sizeof(double[x][y]) );
...
free(array);
```

Comment: Of course that's not going to work with matrix multiplication, you'll need to pass in 3 dimensions or more, or just one...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My matrix algebra is very rusty, but it's easy enough to change the number of parameters or array dimensions.

Comment: "For matrix multiplication, the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix." ;) so if using `x` and `y` like this, then x must be y... I guess the intent was that this has 3 dimensions because there are the dimensions of two source matrix and the target dimensions are rows from first, cols from second

Comment: Actually I'm using intel C compiler. However, it does not work in intel compiler... 
In intel compiler, Should we use another method??

Comment: @Song It works just fine. If you are using some very old version you might have to compile with `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the size(M*N) of both arrays, if both array sizes are equal, to the function mat_mul() as follows:

```
void mat_mul(int M, int N, double A[M][N], double B[M][N],double C[M][N]){
      //code here
}
```

The whole solution after tweaking your code would be:

```
void mat_mul(int M,int N,double A[M][N], double B[M][N],double C[M][N])
{

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
        printf("%lf ",C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
    double A[3][3];
    double C[3][3] = { 0 };
    double B[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) B[i][i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        A[i][j] = 3 * i + j;
    }
}
mat_mul(3,3,A, B, C);

return 0;
}
```

Instead of 3,3 you can send the matrix size M,N respectively to mat_mul() function.

Comment: @Song It works just fine. https://godbolt.org/z/ndf4fWsY8